# ERROR Error sending request to Flask: [TypeError: undefined is not a function] error in my react native metro builder console

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, mobile, flask-restful

I'm trying to connect my react native app with the flask API I have the correct device IP set in my react code and it is also recieving the requests from the Flask server

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Aug/2023 21:26:16] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Aug/2023 21:31:15] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Aug/2023 21:31:33] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

However, my react app is not getting the correct format of JSON it is expecting altho I can see the logs with the following mesage: [My Metro Builder Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhlBI.png)

My react app expects a JSON with a key value pair 'object_type' which is exactly what my metro builder logs display as atttached in the pic above , My react snippet is below:

```
try {
        //my code
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
        });
        const data = await response.json();
      //this part tells me what Im recieving
    console.log('Received JSON data:', data);

       //code goes here
  );
  if (highestConfidencePrediction.object_type === 'Garbage') {
         //code logic comes here
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending request to Flask:', error);
      }
    };
```

lots of code is cut above to show the real problem, please help